# Is it possible to pass a particular model in a click function?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am having terrible time figuring out how to pass a specified `model` in the function (say `click` function).

I have this model.

**javascript**

```
var Bar = function() {
  this.id = ko.observable();
  this.name = ko.observable();
  this.barItems = ko.observableArray([]);
};

var BarItem = function() {
  this.id = ko.observable();
  this.type = ko.observable();
};

var addBarItem = function(item) {
  // seems that the "item" here is the whole viewmodel
};

var bars = ko.observableArray([]); // the elements here are Bar objects
var selectedBar = ko.observable(); // passed a Bar object
```

**html**

```
<div data-bind="with: selectedBar">
  <p data-bind="text: name></p>
  <div>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: type" />
    <button data-bind="click: $root.addBarItem">Add Bar Item</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Once I clicked the **Add Bar Item**, it is getting the `Bar` object. How can I pass the `BarItem` in there?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the documentation: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html#note-2-accessing-the-event-object-or-passing-more-parameters?

Comment: You're not actually showing your *model*, you just show some functions which you assign to some variables.

Comment: @connexo hi, I have a full running code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33518437/how-to-push-object-to-an-observablearray please take a look.

Comment: @nemesv yes, but please have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33518437/how-to-push-object-to-an-observablearray thanks

Comment: Why are you not using `Bar` and `BarItem` as properties of *one* viewmodel?

Comment: @connexo do you think you can show me how it could be done? I am really struggling figuring out the way.

Comment: Inside your `with: selectedBar` binding, you are trying to access a `type` property which your `selectedBar` - according to your source code comments - does not have since it is a `Bar`, not a `BarItem`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrate anything you need into your viewmodel. Use this as a starting point.

```
var BarViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.Bar = {
      id: ko.observable(),
      name: ko.observable(),
      barItems: ko.observableArray([])
    };

    self.BarItem = {
      id: ko.observable(),
      type: ko.observable()
    };

    self.addBarItem = function(item) {
      // when referenced within foreach will receive the current item automatically
    };

    self.bars = ko.observableArray([]); // the elements here will be Bar objects
    self.selectedBar = ko.observable(); // passed a Bar object
};

ko.applyBindings(new BarViewModel());
```

Comment: oh okay. so I can something like.. a `<div data-bind="with: BarItem">..fields here..</div>`?